# Not able to Fetch Json

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I want to Fetch a json to display only syn in a div.

its like:--

```
$.getJSON('http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/eba286cdc7f3619674544d80ce94cb1b/stack/json', function(data) {

         //parse the response to display in a div


        });
```

[output format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25wxX.jpg)

---

JSON markup from link:

```
{
    "noun": {
        "syn": [
            "batch",
            "deal",
            "flock",
            "good deal",
            "great deal",
            "hatful",
            "heap",
            "lot",
            "mass",
            "mess",
            "mickle",
            "mint",
            "muckle",
            "peck",
            "pile",
            "plenty",
            "pot",
            "quite a little",
            "raft",
            "sight",
            "slew",
            "spate",
            "tidy sum",
            "wad",
            "push-down list",
            "push-down stack",
            "smokestack",
            "push-down storage",
            "push-down store",
            "agglomerate",
            "chimney",
            "cumulation",
            "cumulus",
            "large indefinite amount",
            "large indefinite quantity",
            "list",
            "listing",
            "memory device",
            "mound",
            "storage device",
            "whole lot",
            "whole slew"
        ]
    },
    "verb": {
        "syn": [
            "pile",
            "heap",
            "arrange",
            "lade",
            "laden",
            "load",
            "load up",
            "set up"
        ],
        "rel": [
            "heap up",
            "pile up",
            "stack away",
            "stack up"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matt not a json.. Check the link i provided in the code..

Comment: You have two arrays. noun.syn and verb.syn. You can use a for loop and iterate thro these two arrays and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON fails to load because of the Same Origin Policy, just append `?callback=?` to your world and it'd work. The updated code,

```
$.getJSON('http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/eba286cdc7f3619674544d80ce94cb1b/stack/json?callback=?', function(data) {
    //parse the response to display in a div
    //you can access the JSON object from the data object.
});
```

Update:

And when you append a `?callback=?` to the URL used in `$.getJSON`, jQuery understands that it's a JSONP request and not a XMLHttpRequest to fetch JSON. Actually the callback parameter can be anything thing, but the value must be `?` to trigger a JSONP request.

When making the request jQuery replaces the parameter something as `?callback=jQuery15107307685413397849_1299439987443`, the value will be unique every time you make a request.

Comment: Very nice! What does the 'callback' param provide that allows the request to go cross domain? Does it trigger jQuery to use some sort of tricks under the hood?

Comment: Yaa i want to know about that one too. Please explain.

Comment: @JAAulde @user: it makes it a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) request.

Comment: But as far as I understand it, JSONP requires server support, and the name of a function call for the server to wrap around the response data. Did you know that server supports JSONP? How is "callback=?" naming a function to call? (Not arguing, just trying to understand)

Comment: @JAAulde the service/server from where your are requesting does support JSONP. What it means is that, whatever you pass on as the value for the `callback` parameter will be used as a callback function with the JSON data as it's argument. [example](http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/eba286cdc7f3619674544d80ce94cb1b/stack/json?callback=test)

Comment: Right, totally understood--that server supports it and whatever you give it, it uses.  But I didn't understand where defined the function named "?" in the example you posted as an answer. I see that you have since edited to explain that jQuery does it under the hood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what problems you're running in to. As is, if you are running the posted code on the domain, 'words.bighugelabs.com', then inside your callback function you can simply access:

```
data.verb.syn
```

or any other properties.  If you're not on that domain, then you're probably running into the problems associated with cross domain scripting restrictions. If that is the case, you'll want to look into JSONP (if the remote server supports it) or a proxying methodology.

Comment: yaa i m on remote server. And thats y its not running i think.

Comment: Ok, you should find out if the remote service has a JSONP version of the API available.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see the JSON response from the URL you've provided. You can do something like this (you could make it more efficient by using a `StringBuilder`):

```
var list;

var syn = data.noun.syn;

for(var i = 0; i < syn.length; i++)
{
    list += syn[i];
}

syn = data.verb.syn;

for(var i = 0; i < syn.length; i++)
{
    list += syn[i];
}

$('#mydiv').append(list);
```

In the future, please be more specific about what the problem is that you're facing -

- Were you not able to fetch the JSON? See @JAAulde's answer; the part about the Same Origin Policy
- Were you not able to parse the JSON? See my answer and take a look at [JSON.org](http://json.org/) or perhaps [this tutorial](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29).
- Was there something else? Please update your question.